# retrieve all fields with same name and type c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a a custom type like the following:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id;
    public List<Child1> C1;
    public List<Child2> C2;

}

public class Child1
{
    public int Id;
}

public class Child2
{
    public int Id;
    public Child3 C3;
}

public class Child3
{
    public int Id;
}
```

I have a list of the Parent class

```
List<Parent> parent = new List<Parent>();
```

What is the best way to get all the Id fields of the 'parent' in a list?

The easiest way would be to use a nested foreach loop but is their a cleaner way of doing it?

I want the Ids of all the Parent Objects as well as the Ids of their recursive Child objects in one List as

```
List<int> AllIds
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is unclear what your goal is. Do you want to simply select the Parent-ids or some child-Ids?

Comment: Any way you slice it, it'll boil down to _some kind_ of nested loop, either explicitly, with LINQ, etc.

Comment: _"The easiest way would be to use a nested foreach loop but is their a cleaner way"_ If that's the easiest way for you and your colleagues, use it. Easy is clean if it works.

Comment: @s.m. In retrospect, it looks like you are correct, the tree will only go three levels deep.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an `AllIDs` property to `Parent`

```
public IEnumerable<int> AllIDs
{
  get
  {
    yield return Id;

    foreach(var child in C1)
    {
      yield return child.Id;
    }

    foreach(var child in C2)
    {
      yield return child.Id;
      yield return child.C3.Id;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do a `SelectMany` on the `parent` variable

```
var ids = parent.SelectMany(p => p.AllIDs).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany` and `Enumerable.Concat`:

```
List<int> allIds = parent
    .SelectMany(p => new[] { p.Id } // or Enumerable.Repeat(p.Id, 1)
        .Concat(p.C1.Select(c => c.Id))
        .Concat(p.C2.Select(c => c.Id)))
    .ToList();
```

If you instead want to know whether an ID was a child or parent ID you could select an anonymous type which contains the type and it's parent-id if available:

```
var allIds = parent
    .SelectMany(p => new[] { new { Type="Parent", p.Id, Parent = (int?)null } }
        .Concat(p.C1.Select(c => new { Type = "Child1", c.Id, Parent = (int?)p.Id }))
        .Concat(p.C2.Select(c => new { Type = "Child2", c.Id, Parent = (int?)p.Id })))
    .ToList();

foreach (var x in allIds)
    Console.WriteLine("ID:{0} Type:{1} Parent-ID:{2}", x.Id, x.Type, x.Parent?.ToString() ?? "no parent");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the LINQ solution

```
List<Parent> parent = new List<Parent>();
var parentIds = parent.
   Select(p => p
       // take C2 ids and C3 ids foreach Parent
      .C2.SelectMany(c2 => new List<string> { c2.Id, c2.C3.Id} )
       // Add each C1 id foreach parent
      .Union(p.C1.Select(c1 => c1.Id))
       // Add its own id
      .Concat(new List<string> { p.id })
   );
```

Answer (score -1):

Get all parent ids:

```
List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();
// populate parent list

int[] parentIds = parents.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray();
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks like OP wants all the children's IDs as well.

Comment: What if we want the Ids of the Child1 and Child2 as well in the same list?

Comment: @s.m. thats correct I want all the children's Id as well